# Understanding __deref_out

Tags: windows, winapi, sal

I am new to Windows programming and I can't seem to find any resources on understanding what this SAL annotation means. I'm basically trying to look for examples so I know exactly what this means both for the caller and the callee.

The MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383701(v=vs.85).aspx) was of no help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is just a combination of _deref (callee will dereference the pointer and it may not be NULL) and _out (callee will only assign and not expect a value to be passed in).  Be more explicit about what you don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

"deref" means there's a level of indirection in the passed in pointer. So instead of:

```
DWORD Function(BYTE* pBuffer);
// pBuffer is a pointer to a BYTE buffer
```

You might  have:

```
DWORD Function(BYTE** ppBuffer);
// pBuffer is a pointer to another pointer
// To access the buffer, dereference the pointer:
// BYTE* pBuffer = *ppBuffer;
```

"opt" means the value is optional, that is `ppBuffer` may be equal to `nullptr`.